# Apache server: can't render php and html at once

Tags: php, html, apache, ubuntu, httpd.conf

I'm running a Ubuntu Server with Apache.  PHP and HTML both run correctly using their respective file extensions.  When I try to add PHP code into an HTML file it renders the PHP but not the HTML when I use the following in httpd.conf

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the code you want to render (PHP and HTML). If you have ANY PHP in a file, it needs to be named with a .php extension, as .php files render HTML codes exactly the same as .html files do. (.php extension tells the server there is extra stuff to process).

Comment: @mesh thats wrong, you can configure Apache to render HTML files as PHP

Comment: Check the headers your browser is getting from Apache, you may have lost the `Content-Type: text/html` header for some reason.

Comment: @petah - Yes, of course, but only with mod_rewrite or different header configurations. The standard Apache installation with PHP will indeed follow what I said.

Comment: @mesh: mod_php couldn't care less what you call your files. What's important is that Apache hands the file over to the PHP interpreter properly. remember, there's no such thing as a "php script". There's merely files that have php code blocks embedded within.

Comment: @mesh RTFM please, you can use the `AddHandler` directive to make HTML files be interpreted as PHP, likewise you can also do this for CSS or JS files.

Comment: It's rendering the php fine, it shows text instead of html though.

Comment: Problem solved!
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
Was is the PHP code and throwing everything off!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Was in the PHP code and throwing everything off!

Answer (score 0):

Doing a little goggling it looks a lot like you should have

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html
```

notice that the `AddHandler` does not have a `application/` in front of it.

Found this info at http://www.honeytechblog.com/how-to-fix-applicationx-httpd-php-trouble-in-getting-php-to-parse/

Comment: This causes the webpages to be downloaded.

Comment: Can you check the content-type that Apache is sending?  You may not need the first line `AddType`

Comment: When I remove the first line the html renders correctly but the php does not. :(

Comment: What is the AddType or AddHandler you have for the .php extension?

Comment: I don't have any, the default apache settings pick it up after an install.  There's no htaccess file for it nor httpd.conf

Comment: Problem solved!
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
Was is the PHP code and throwing everything off!